# Writing a comment to Q/A in `Review | First Posts`

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

In Review | First Posts
(filtered with [delphi])

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10441865

The question was tagged [delphi] although not related to Delphi.

I wrote a comment to the question, asking 'How is this related to Delphi?' and at the moment of [Enter] to terminate the comment editor I was presented with

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You
>   didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality
>   post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

Obviously, the [Enter] I pressed to terminate the comment editor, triggered the review selection, whichever was 'active' at the time I wrote the comment, and misjudged my intention. Is this a bug?

Or, I simple did something wrong. Please educate me!

Note! My question is about `writing a comment to a Q/A in 'Review` (especially 'First Posts') and how to terminate the comment editor so it doesn't trigger any of the Review buttons.

Comment: First, you may want to read [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: @psubsee2003 I know, I've read it before. My question is *not* about reviews or review-audits! My question is about `writing a comment to a Q/A in 'Review` (especially 'First Posts') and how to terminate the comment editor so it doesn't trigger any of the Review buttons. I will edit my question to make it clearer.

Comment: In First Posts, when you try to comment on a "known good" post, you fail, so your problem is unfortunately that you tried to comment on a "good audit".

Comment: Or maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "terminate the comment editor".  You typed a comment, you hit enter, your comment was  submitted.  Since it was an audit, that's when you failed.  There's no way you could have passed the audit and still leave a comment.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Your understanding is correct regarding "terminate the comment editor". Please reread why I entered a comment. It was not a "known good" post because it was tagged inappropriately. I conclude it was an erroneous review-audit and move on. Cheers!

Comment: The solution is simple: Make your comment last.

Comment: @Deduplicator What do you mean, last of what? Please elaborate.

Comment: @TomBrunberg anytime you filter on tags, you are going to see this problem.  For audits, the system injects a tag to match your filter, it doesn't find an audit that already matches your tag.  So when filtering by tag and reviewing, if you see an erronenous tag, you need to go to the actual post and check it.  If you see the real post without the tag, you know it is an audit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That makes sense and explains the problem. I recall sometimes before seing posts with erroneous tag according my filter, but then I must have skipped the review, possibly because content being out of my knowledge area. Ok, I will not pay attention to this kind of errors. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have run into a limitation of the review audit system when you are reviewing posts filtered by tag.

When you filter by tag and the system decides you should get an audit, it does not go specifically looking for a question matching your tag filters, it just pulls the next audit and injects your filtered tags into the review to make it "look" like it has your tags.

So your action was perfectly normal.  If I happened across a review with an erroneous tag, I would want to leave a comment asking why, or edit it out.  But either action would fail a "known good" audit immediately.

Because of the potential for audits, I will take 1 extra step to be sure I am not getting an audit - I will click through to see the original post.  If the original post has the tag, then you can be assured you can safely leave the comment (or edit the erroneous tag) and complete the review.  If it doesn't (and the votes do not match what you see on the review), then you know you have an audit, and you can handle the post how the system wants you to handle it to pass the audit.